# Difference between swift v1 auth and v2 auth?

Tags: authentication, openstack-swift, keystone

Can I say tempauth belongs to v1 auth, or keystone belongs v2 auth? How to judge a authentication is v1 or v2?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I say tempauth belongs to v1 auth, or keystone belongs v2 auth?

Sort of. Tempauth is a configuration which works entirely in the proxy server. Keystone authentication works "like" OAUTH. You ask a token to Keystone and uses that token to perform operation on SWIFT.  Tempauth was made for tests purpose only. And Keystone was made for production environments.

> How to judge a authentication is v1 or v2?

That is a tricky question. If don't know anything about the Swift cluster it's not something guessable. If your provider sent you anything about the authentication, you can check if you have to connect with keystone. And if he/she is not using Keystone, he/she could be using another authentication method like ldap or swauth. Tips: usually keystone runs on port 5000.